# Unable to access UDV variable

Tags: jmeter

in below script i am trying to access user defined variable and modify the data and passing the value to post data using the variable `"data"`.But after modifying the data it is not being sent to http request.

```
String temp = vars.get("${json}"); //access UDV data
temp = temp.replaceAll("__"," ");
vars.put("data",temp); //pass the data to another udv "data"
```

Please let me know whether there is any mistake in my above script

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `+1`? show input and expected output

Comment: appologise i have added wrong data..i have updated the code now pls check..i am trying to replace some special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an [User Defined Variable](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) called `json` which is created like:

[image]

then you need to change your code like:

```
String temp = vars.get("json")
```

or alternatively use "Parameters" section of the [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing the variable incorrectly

*`String temp = vars.get("${json}"); //access UDV data`* is wrong

`String temp = vars.get("json"); //access UDV data`

refer [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for more details